# echo variable in bash gives different value

Tags: bash, centos

I am getting the output like this:

```
ps -ef | grep xyz | grep -v grep | grep -v ruby |  awk '{print $8}'
```

as **xyz**

but when I am assign this value to the variable and print the variable then I am getting some weird output like this-

```
string='ps -ef | grep xyz | grep -v grep | grep -v ruby |  awk '{print $8}''
echo $string
```

Output:

```
output= sudo sh sh xyz
```

**How can I just get the output as `xyz`**

Comment: I'm not sure how you are even getting that output.  You assign a string and output the string.  But, I think what you actually want is `string="$(ps -ef | grep xyz | grep -v grep | grep -v ruby |  awk '{print $8}')"`.  Which is sort of what your output looks like.  If you are getting multiple results, then the string `xyz` exists in all of those lines.  I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but one more `| grep xyz` would give you what you want...

Comment: @Jason, It did not make any difference. Still getting the same output-

Comment: Okay, try just `ps -ef | grep xyz | grep -v grep | grep -v ruby` and see what you get.  That should clear things up for you.  However many lines of output you get is how much output you will get after the awk call.

Comment: This is what I get if I run the command without print line-
deploy   32562     1  0 03:13 ?        00:03:19 xyz 3.2.5 yzx [0 of 40 busy]

Comment: The command `echo "deploy 32562 1 0 03:13 ? 00:03:19 xyz 3.2.5 yzx [0 of 40 busy" | awk '{print $8}'` outputs `xyz`... Try my command in my original comment.  The quotes around the command substitution may be important here. Also `echo $0` to make sure you are using bash...

Comment: you can use : STRING=$(ps -ef |grep xyz | grep -v grep | grep -v ruby | awk '{print $8}' )    and then for print use : printf "%s\n" "$TTTT"

Comment: please dont copy from here and try to type into your script (because of character set)